# Chat app using IOS and Java

Tags: java, php, iphone, ios, chat

I need to do a CHAT APP for iPhone . I just look some sites on chat app hierarchy , those all good to know such as : [Chat app for IOS using Php server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/) ..etc...

This s good enough to achieve my task . But I'm looking at IOS app with JAVA (server side) . I didn't see any samples or tutorials or materials on JAVA .

I just need to know , Can I go through on PHP only , Or else is there any possible to do on Java with some research .

I like to do on Java . Please let me know , If any materials related to it .

Thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Openfire Chat Server**](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/).

Openfire is a real time collaboration (RTC) server licensed under the Open Source Apache License. It uses the only widely adopted open protocol for instant messaging, XMPP (also called Jabber). Openfire is incredibly easy to setup and administer, but offers rock-solid security and performance.

Easy to configure and use.

Guide for installing Openfire Server:

1. http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/install-guide.html
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFHiRYRx79E

Comment: Thanks for your answer . And good to know about Openfire . Do you know any materials other than installation . I mean about the practical material for chat app using of it.

Comment: You should be having knowledge of using XMPP from IOS side. First try out yourself and then if issues are there post it on Stackoverflow.

Comment: : actually I'm looking like call center software .  For Chat between users , This s good enough . Do you know any tutorials for this ( Many operators on server side to handle clients ).

Comment: You can have a look at the following Widgets that can be embeddable in your site for Live Support:
1. Chatango
2. Meboo.me
3. JWChat
4. CBox
5. Mibew Web Messenger
6. AjaxChat for WordPress
7. AJAX Chat
8. phpFreeChat
9. iJab
10. Ajax IM